# Is there a way to export/restore a database using Doctrine2?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, backup

Basically, I want the administrator of a web site to be able to make database backups and have the ability to restore them without making him to mess with SQL commands. I don't mind about the output format but SQL would be fine. I only need to backup the data, not the schema.

I'm using Symfony2 and Doctrine with MySQL.

I was wondering if there is any (easy) way to do this, something like:

```
$doctrine->dumpToFile('filename.sql');
...
$doctrine->restoreFromFile('filename.sql');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to dump fixtures using Doctrine.

You should use [Propel ORM](http://www.propelorm.org/) - it was so in Symfony-1.4 and there was possibility to dump fixtures, and it is so in Symfony-2.0 with Propel 1.6.

It is [well documented](http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/), [easily installed](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle) and [naturally used](http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/working-with-symfony2.html) within Symfony-2.0

Comment: it's a shame doctrine can't do that @_@